# Does hashcode number represent the memory address?

Tags: java

I have learned that hashcode is a Unique Identification reference number, which is a hexadecimal number.
My doubt is, does the reference number represents the memory address of the object?

For example:

```
Employeee e1=new Employee();
System.out.println(e1.hashcode());
```

Will this code return me the memory address of my object?

Comment: No, it is just an identifer.

Comment: It's a unique value for that object; it need not represent the memory address.  Even if it did, what would it mean to you?  What would you do with that knowledge?

Comment: It is **not** a unique value for that object. It is just a value that is hopefully as unique as it gets (if implemented right). `Object#hashCode` is only unique if pointers are 32-bit.

Comment: @duffymo There are lot of operations that u can do knowing the hashcode buddy.I think u r unaware of that

Comment: I'm not your buddy.  Please enlighten me as to what those operations might be.

Comment: I believe duffymo ment what would you do with the memory address, not what would you do with a hashcode

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105420/java-object-hashcode-address-or-random

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hashcode is not a unique identification. It's just a number that helps you distinguish objects. Two different objects may have the same hash code and it is fine.

HashCode characteristics:

1. If obj1 and obj2 are equal, they must have the same hash code.
2. If obj1 and obj2 have the same hash code, they do not have to be equal.

Comment: 2. is not exactly a rule :)

Comment: @Michal Borek I have read that only string objects can have same hashcode coz they may get stored in string constant pool, the rest of the objects always have a different hashcode? what do u think of it

Comment: Thanx for ur comments guys,I think I need to do a lot more research nw!!

Comment: @MarkoTopolink it is a rule due to the [pidigionhole principle](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle). You could create more objects than possible values, when that happens two objects that are not equal must have the same hash code.

Comment: The 2. is correct!. "It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results. However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hash tables."

Please Check: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily the memory address. It should be kept different for different objects. But it might be anything. You can also override default `hashCode` definition with your own.

Comment: In fact, for recent JVMs the default behavior is that the identity hashcode is not even related to a memory address.

Answer (score 3):

If `Employee` class hasn't overridden the `hashCode()` method , then it will use the one defined in its super class, probably `Object` class . [hashCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) in Object class says ,

```
As much as is reasonably practical, the hashCode method defined by class Object
does return distinct integers for distinct objects. (This is typically 
implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, 
but this implementation technique is not required by the JavaTM 
programming language.)
```

So, in short it may or may not depending upon the implementation.Suppose, if `Employee` class has overridden the `hashCode()` as(though bad practice and useless) :

```
public int hashCode() {
   return 10;
}
```

Then, you can see that it doesn't return a memory address here.

Answer (score 3):

Hashcode is a number used by JVM for hashing in order to store and retrieve the objects. For example, when we add an object in hashmap, JVM looks for the hashcode implentation to decide where to put the object in memory. When we retrieve an object again hashcode is used to get the location of the object. Note that hashcode is not the actual memory address but its a link for JVM to fetch the object from a specified location with a complexity of O(1).

Answer (score 2):

According to Java documentation:

As much as is reasonably practical, the `hashCode` method defined by class `Object` does return distinct integers for distinct objects. (This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not required by the Java programming language.)

Answer (score 2):

`hashCode` is the native implementation which provides the memory address to a certain extent.

Any ways you can ovveride it.

If you  [**look close at API**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29)

> If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.

I do not know how much you understand from others answers but my doubts were clear after 
  I read

[**The 3 things you should know about hashCode()**](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/09/04/the-3-things-you-should-know-about-hashcode/) by  @Ralf Sternberg

Answer (score 2):

Simple Answer **NO**

`A hashcode is an integer value that represents the state of the object upon which it was called. That is why an Integer that is set to 1 will return a hashcode of "1" because an Integer's hashcode and its value are the same thing. A character's hashcode is equal to it's ASCII character code. If you write a custom type you are responsible for creating a good hashCode implementation that will best represent the state of the current instance.`

So for your class you can implement the hashcode Method and return whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

The hashcode for objects is implementation-specific, but I would highly doubt any JVM implementation would use the memory address. Since garbage collection is a central feature of Java, that means the object could be moved and thereby have different memory addresses during its lifetime, even if its  contents remain unchanged (and this would violate the hashcode spec).

Comment: It could be the int value of the initially valid pointer, though.

Comment: Yes, that's true -- but you could never safely assume `hashcode == memory address`

Comment: Of course, especially since pointers can be more than 32-bit, so that would preclude even the theoretical chance.

Comment: @TonythePony does that mean this is total BS (where they say it IS the memory address) https://dzone.com/articles/working-with-hashcode-and-equals-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Hashcode is the 32 bit signed integer that is uniquely assigned to that object. It is the result of the hash function when inserting into the hashmap